# Gradle excessive source code recompilations

Tags: gradle, teamcity, build.gradle

I'm facing a problem when running TeamCity build with three gradle steps.

The steps are : Assemble, Test, Upload archives.

Gradle recompiles source code on each step execution (it seems that it has to - each execution runs separately) - which ends up in total **10** minutes. When tasks are executed in one step, it taske only **3** minutes.

Most of the log output in "Test" and "Upload archives" steps is up-to-date

```
:project-api:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
```

but it still takes 2 minutes to make all excessive actions in "Upload step", before it really starts to upload artifacts.

I can't just configure tasks "dependsOn", because sometimes "Upload" can be made without "Test" and so on. I tried to increase **resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor**, but seems that it is not the option.

Is there a way to avoid these overhead from task execution split?

Comment: I think the problem is the three TC build steps. I believe TC creates a new working directory for each build step, effectively negating any incremental build support provided by Gradle. Why not consolidate into a single TC build step which executes all three tasks? Essentially, create a build step analogous to executing `gradle assemble test uploadArchives` from the command line.

Comment: @MarkVieira the problem is Gradle does not follow the execution order in my case. I have a multi-project gradle build. When i execute these commands in one step, i can see that content of some modules is uploaded before other modules are tested and so on. Probably this is caused by gradle parallel execution.

Comment: This is due to the way Gradle is constructing the task dependency graph. If you want all projects tested before any are uploaded you can do that via task dependencies. Look at [this thread](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how-do-i-run-tests-in-all-subprojects-before-uploading-any) for a solution.

Comment: @MarkVieira thanks. Despite my initial unwillingness to play with "dependsOn", I think it's the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments, the problem is caused by a separation of TeamCity build steps - each step execution is isolated, that's why Gradle can't use cached information from previous steps.

I solved it by combining this three build steps in a single build step and adding proper `dependsOn` relation. As you could see, I wanted to avoid the dependency from `Upload` to `Test`, but it was impossible in this scenario.